# CakePHP navigation bar with logged user information

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to create a navigation bar similar to the one here in StackOverflow or the one in most social networks, where it shows the user information (name, profile pic) or if there is no logged user then it shows a log in button.

I read this kind of view are supposed to be implemented as **element** using `$this>element('name');` inside a view. The thing is that I don't know how to get the user information within the **element**. How can I do this?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element

Comment: Yeah, I already read this, but it is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller assign the user's current information to a view variable.

```
public function index()
{
    $user = <-- assign current user info
    $this->set('user',$user);
}
```

In your `index.ctp` view file pass that information to the element to be rendered.

```
echo $this->element('user_info',array('myvar'=>$user));
```

In your `user_info.ctp` element file display the user information.

```
echo $myvar['email'];
```

Comment: It's basically this, anyway, playing around with the code will almost definitely give you the answer

Comment: If this bar is going to be on every page, it would probably be a better idea to move the above into `AppController`'s `beforeFilter()` or `beforeRender()`